# How can I create an instance of an arbitrary Array type at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I'm trying to deserialize an array of an type unknown at compile time. At runtime I've discovered the type, but I don't know how to create an instance.

Something like:

```
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

which doesn't work because there is no parameterless constructor, Array doesn't seem to have any constructor.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx).

Comment: Slight problem with that. If I know that the type is a System.String[] and I Array.CreateInstance() I get a System.String[][]

Comment: Yes, you pass in the *element* type, not the final array type.

Answer (score 12):

You can use one of Array's CreateInstance overloads e.g.:-

```
object o = Array.CreateInstance(type, 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

Quite an old post, but while answering a new question, though of posting a related example of creating a multi-dimensional array.

Assuming the type (`elementType`) as `int` and a two-dimensional array for example.

```
var size = new[] { 2, 3 };                
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), size);
```

When it's two dimensional, for example, it can be populated as

```
var value = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; j++)
        arr.SetValue(value++, new[] { i, j });
//arr = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use expression trees for performance. For e.g. if you have array *type*, `type` you could do

```
var ctor = type.GetConstructors().First(); // or find suitable constructor
var argsExpr = ctor.GetParameters().Select(x => Expression.Constant(0)); 
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.New(ctor, argsExpr)).Compile();
```

This just returns an empty array. Probably not very useful. MSDN states `GetConstructors` doesn't guarantee any order, so you might need a logic to find right constructor with right parameters to instantiate with correct size. For e.g. you could do:

```
static Func<object> ArrayCreateInstance(Type type, params int[] bounds) // can be generic too
{
    var ctor = type
        .GetConstructors()
        .OrderBy(x => x.GetParameters().Length) // find constructor with least parameters
        .First();

    var argsExpr = bounds.Select(x => Expression.Constant(x)); // set size
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.New(ctor, argsExpr)).Compile();
}
```

The same can be achieved much easier with `Expression.NewArrayBounds` instead of `Expression.New`, more over it works if all you got is array element type, not array type itself. Demo:

```
static Func<object> ArrayCreateInstance(Type type, params int[] bounds) // can be generic too
{
    var argsExpr = bounds.Select(x => Expression.Constant(x)); // set size
    var newExpr = Expression.NewArrayBounds(type.GetElementType(), argsExpr);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(newExpr).Compile();
}

// this exercise is pointless if you dont save the compiled delegate, but for demo purpose:

x = string[] {...
y = ArrayCreateInstance(x.GetType(), 10)(); // you get 1-d array with size 10

x = string[,,] {...
y = ArrayCreateInstance(x.GetType(), 10, 2, 3)(); // you get 3-d array like string[10, 2, 3]

x = string[][] {...
y = ArrayCreateInstance(x.GetType(), 10)(); // you get jagged array like string[10][]
```

Just change `type.GetElementType()` to simply `type` if what you're passing is element type itself.