# How to generate array type using a given type?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, code-generation

I am working on a code generator written in C#.
This code generator reads a xml file and generate a .cs file.
So far we have assumed that all fields are string which is not true and I have changed the code so it can generate a type according to the specified type in our xml :

```
<MyField>
   <Name>Name</Name>
   <Type>String</Type>
</MyField>
```

But there might be some fields that can have more than one values (Multiselectable fields) that have another attribute (Options for example) that list all possible options.
What I would like to do is to generate the array type for any given type .So that I can process my fields first and if there are some fields optional I can convert their type to an array.

Here's what I want to do :

```
Type fieldType=typeof(string);
Type fieldType=GetArrayTypeof(fieldType);
```

How should I implement `GetArrayTypeOf` function ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493490/converting-a-string-to-a-class-name

Comment: @BCdotNET I think this question is not the same as mine because I don't want to make a generic type like List<T> but I'd like to generate an array.

Comment: Then replace the generic type with an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400900/how-can-i-create-an-instance-of-an-arbitrary-array-type-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get type from its string name you can use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

To get array type from item use [Type.MakeArrayType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc2e4ft8(v=vs.110).aspx) instance method:

```
 string itemTypeName = "System.Int32";

 Type itemType = Type.GetType(itemTypeName);

 Console.WriteLine(itemType.MakeArrayType());
```

Comment: Well I thought there might be a way without creating an instance :)

Comment: Funny that I haven't seen this method before :D